create table of all unique options for panel design - biology research
I'm not a programmer.I'm a biologist and I have Epitopes (=the thing that can mark cells) in differen peak channel (=basically color emission detected). I have to have all my "unique" Epitope options (=I need all cell markers) but cannot have repeated colors= must not have repeated "peak channel". I'm restricted by having each Epitope in only few specific fluorophore (thus, only specific peak channels).
I would like to write a code which recieves a table with all my available epitopes in all their fluorophores, and gives back tables with all my combination options. I tried to write the code using chat GPT and claude but it didn't work.
the input will be for example something like this:



Fluorophore
Peak Channel
Epitope




Alexa Fluor 700
R4
I-A/I-E


BV650
V11
I-A/I-E


FITC
B2
Ly6C


PerCP/Cy5.5
B9
Ly6C


Alexa Fluor 700
R4
Ly6C



in this case of only 2 epitopes I expect 5 otional combos (as there are 2 of the same peak which cannot be together). one of the combo outputs would be:
Panel 1:



Fluorophore
Peak Channel
Epitope




Alexa Fluor 700
R4
I-A/I-E


FITC
B2
Ly6C



Even better would be if the input would be a long table of all my available epitopes+color and I could also give a list of the specific epitopes I would like for the experiment.
Also, it is important I get all the options of combinations, as there are other biological considerations to make.
Thank you!!
I tried to write the code using chat GPT and claude but it didn't work.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. you want expand.grid, as a starting point. Excluding overlaps as a second question if results are unsatisfactory.

... e.g. expand.grid(unique(df$Fluorophore), unique(df$Epitope), unique(df$Peak.Channel)).
